# Best way to create dynamic view model in MVC razor on the fly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

The problem is that a have to show dynamically the fields on the web page using MVC and Razor VE depending on the user permissions from the database. Thus, every user has its form and field mappings setup and depending on it I have to show/hide the fields on the form. So, I am thinking of the best applicable approach to implement such a behavior.....

Any ideas would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to pass dynamic object use ViewBag, but in my option normal model is better options. For hiding and showing different section: did you think about partial views and render it were are they need? You can pass to it "properties" of your model.